# webob cookies

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies, session

I am not able to set cookies using following statements

```
        self.request.headers['Cookie'] = 'uniqueid = ',unique_identifier
        self.request.headers['Cookie'] = 'nickname = ',nickname
```

as 
     self.request.cookies

is returning null dictionary in another request.

environment is python on google app engine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the cookies in the request does nothing to the cookie on the client.

You need to set the "Set-Cookie" header in the response to the client.

You could use something like this (untested by me) [Google App Engine Cookie class](http://appengine-cookbook.appspot.com/recipe/a-simple-cookie-class/)

Comment: It is not getting set although theoretically it should

Answer (score 4):

The [WebOb Reference explains set_cookie](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webob/en/stable/reference.html#id3) well - if youre on a framework using the WebOb Response (not valid for Google App Engine, it uses an own Repsonse)